# Mysterious and weird lines after using uni-form

Tags: python, css, django, uniform

I'm using django-uni-form to display forms. I've included all the css and javascript (notably jquery) in the page. But now I get some weird looking lines. The image below show how it looks:

http://i243.photobucket.com/albums/ff176/cwalkrox/uni-form1.jpg

You can notice that for username and email address, the lines are aligned with the upper side of text inputs while for two passwords, the lines are below the password inputs. In uni-form's official website, I can't see any line in the 3 examples. Even if it gives me some lines, should it be consistent?

So the strange story doesn't stop here. The jquery can highlight the selected inputs. But the ways it highlights username, email and password are still inconsistent. The following images prove it:

i243.photobucket.com/albums/ff176/cwalkrox/uni-form2.jpg

i243.photobucket.com/albums/ff176/cwalkrox/uni-form3.jpg

So every problems seem to stem from the mysterious lines. So how this happens?

BTW, the page I show you is rendered with the form of django-registration. The rendering snippet is:

```
<form action="" method="post" class="uniForm">
<fieldset>
  {{ form|as_uni_form }}
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: try removing label <fieldset>

Comment: It seems to be a unique issue in IE. Add following line into css solves the problem: .uniForm, .uniForm fieldset, .uniForm .ctrlHolder, .uniForm .formHint, .uniForm .buttonHolder, .uniForm .ctrlHolder ul{ zoom:1; }

Comment: Ezequiel Marquez's suggestion seems to be a magic fix. It seems that fieldset isn't recommended in uni-form then.

Answer (score 0):

Those lines are due to the css files included in django-uniform: uni-form.css, uni-form-generic.css and uni-form.jquery.css.

It seems weird but at least in my case (a pinax project) the forms look better without the provided css.

my 2 cents